# Refresh page after function has been called

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way that I can run a function then call `window.location.reload()` to refresh the page? Currently when I do this the page is refreshing but the function isn't running.

```
function postComment() {
   var name;
   if (document.getElementById("yourName").value == "") {
      name = "(Anonymous)";
   } else  {
      name = document.getElementById("yourName").value;
   }
   var uri = "http://tgg.tcs.com/AP/Open/Service.svc/comment?name=" + name;
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
   }
   xhr.send(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("comment").value));

}
```

Comment: Sure but you need to show us what that function does and how you are calling both of them. If it's ajax, that is asynchronous and you would be aborting the ajax if not calling sequence properly

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is posting a comment using `XMLHttpRequest()` which I believe is asynchronous...

Comment: which is exactly what I suspected... `ajax` is generic term for `XMLHttpRequest`. Need to show us your code

Comment: @charlietfl do you need to see anything else?

Comment: where's the reload being called? I already know that it is outside of the `onreadystatechange ` callback.  That's where the reload needs to happen if you want to see that alert

Comment: I was calling it just after `xhr.send` but removed it as it was stopping the function from running

Comment: takes time for the request to be made which is why you handle the response inside the callback. Any code after the request will continue to execute even while request is in progress

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for explaining that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a callback

```
function yourFunction(arg, callback) {
    doSomeStuff(arg);
    callback();
}

yourFunction('argument', window.location.reload);
```

If doSomeStuff function is async, you have to do

```
function yourFunction(arg, callback) {
    doSomeStuff(arg, callback);
}

yourFunction('argument', window.location.reload);
```

also, if you refresh the page, you will refresh the scripts as well, so it depends on what does your function do, you may need a cookie if the data the function generates has to be persistant